# Can someone please explain why I'm getting a seg fault error

Tags: c, debugging

This code compiles successfully but when I debug it shows a SIGSEV seg fault error. Can someone help please?

```c
char *_strdup(char *str)
{
   int i, size = 0;
   char *mp;

   if (str == NULL)
   {
        return (NULL);
   }
   for (; str[size] != '0'; size++)
       mp = malloc(size * sizeof(str) + 1);
       /* + 1 to get last part of the str */
   if (mp == 0)
   {
       return (NULL);
   }
   else
   {
       for (; i < size; i++)
       {
           mp[i] = str[i];
       }
   }
   return (mp);
}
```

Comment: `str[size] != '0'` should be `str[size] != '\0'`. The former is checking for the ascii character `0` whereas the latter is checking for the string NUL terminator. Also, looks like you intended to have a `;` at the end of that line as it seems to be for getting the string length. `for (; str[size] != '\0'; size++);`

Comment: It was that missing `;` that misled me, the allocation should be `mp = malloc(size + 1);`. Also, you forgot to write the string terminator.

Comment: `for (; i < size; i++)` is wrong as well. `i` is *indeterminate* at that point, for the comparator and increment a bogus. Turn up your warning levels and treat them as fatal errors (because that's exactly what they are).

Comment: A part from what has already been commented, the overall approach is wrong. Why do you call `malloc` in a loop? This is what you should do: 1. determine the string length. 2. Allocate memory for the new string. 3. Copy the old string into the new string.

Comment: Side note: `return (mp)`: it's unusual (and unnecessary) to put the value to be returned between parentheses. It makes the return startement look like a function call which it is not. This is mostly done by beginners.

Comment: i should’ve initialised i, that’s correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just because it compiles successfully, this does not mean that your code is correct. It just means that *syntactically* the compiler is fine. I hope you use the maximum warning level and correct your code until all warnings and errors are gone.

You have multiple problems:

1. You seem to look for the terminating end-of-string marker. But instead of the correct `'\0'` you typed `'0'`. This can lead to a much too big size, depending where a zero digit is found. Depending on your system, a segmentation fault is also possible.
2. `sizeof` is an operator that yields the size of its argument, in your case the size of a pointer. `str` is of type `char *`. Effectively you allocate too much, but this is harmless.
3. The `for` loop uses the memory allocation as its body. I'm sure you didn't mean this, but there is no empty statement. So you are allocating multiple memory spaces, which are leaks in the end.

   An empty statement is a single semicolon or an empty pair of curly braces.

   What you most probably want to achieve is to find the number of characters that `str` points to. You can get it by calling `strlen(str)`.
4. `i` is not initialized, it can have any value. This can lead to a segmentation fault, if it starts with a negative value.
5. You did not add the end-of-string marker in the duplicate. Depending on the other code we don't see, this can lead to segmentation faults.

This is a possible solution without calling `strlen()`:

```c
char *_strdup(const char *str)
{
    int i;
    int size;
    char *mp;

    if (str == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size = 0; str[size] != '\0'; size++)
    {
        /* just looking for the end of the string */
    }
    size++;
    /* + 1 for the end-of-string marker */

    mp = malloc(size);
    if (mp == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        mp[i] = str[i];
    }
    return mp;
}
```

I made a bit more:

1. Use separate variable definitions, it avoid errors and eases maintenance.
2. `return` is not a function and needs no parentheses for its expression.
3. Put the initialization of the index variable where it belongs, in the initializing statement of `for`. This way everything about this index is at one place.
4. Consider the end-of-string marker by incrementing `size`. This eases the following code.
5. Since `sizeof (char)` is 1, it can be ommitted at the calculation of the needed memory size.
6. Compare `mp` with `NULL` instead of `0`. It is a pointer, and this is C, not C++.

Comment: i should’ve initialised i, that’s correct, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your variable i has been declared but not initialized so a random number is used in your for(; i < size;
Just add `int i = 0, size = 0;`  at the beginning or change your for statement to  `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)`

This was the reason for your segmentation fault. Some other issues:
As mentioned in comments string termination character is not '0'. It's either 0 or '\0'.
You are calling `malloc` on each iteration of your for statement. This causes memory leak.Just call it once after you got your string size right. This is fixed by putting a semicolon after the for.
Maybe something like this.

```
char *_strdup (char *str)
{
  int i, size;
  char *mp;

  if (str == NULL)
    {
      return (NULL);
    }
  for (size = 0; str[size] != 0; size++);
  mp = malloc (size * sizeof (str) + 1);
  /* + 1 to get last part of the str */
  if (mp == 0)
    {
      return (NULL);
    }
  else
    {
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      mp[i] = str[i];
    }
    }
  return (mp);
}
```

Comment: That's just _one_ problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you’re right. i thought writing i, size = 0; would initialise both, but i was wrong. thank you